# Invalid command 'Order', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration

Tags: 7

I'm trying to deploy an instance of Drupal with Cloud Foundry. Everything loads up and seems to start correctly, but when I try to hit the page I get the following error in the logs.

> ../.htaccess: Invalid command 'Order', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration

I'm using [cloudfoundry/php-buildpack](https://github.com/cloudfoundry/php-buildpack).

I was able to get the app to load the install page and run by commenting out this line in the .htaccess file.

```
Order allow,deny
```

However, I feel like this may cause security issues, and I really want a better fix to this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[PHP buildpack](http://github.com/cloudfoundry/php-buildpack) is currently using Apache HTTP Server 2.4. You see that error message because the Order directive has been deprecated in Apache HTTP Server 2.4.

You can either:

#### Update the configuration file for Apache HTTP Server 2.4

Instructions for migrating can be found on [Upgrading to 2.4 from 2.2](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/upgrading.html#run-time).

#### Enable the [mod_access_compat](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_access_compat.html) module for Apache HTTP Server 2.4

This will allow you to keep using the older configuration style. To do this, you should copy [this file](https://github.com/cloudfoundry/php-buildpack/blob/master/defaults/config/httpd/2.4.x/extra/httpd-modules.conf) from the build pack, place it in the root of your project directory under .bp-config/httpd/extra/httpd-modules.conf, and uncomment [line #27](https://github.com/cloudfoundry/php-buildpack/blob/master/defaults/config/httpd/2.4.x/extra/httpd-modules.conf#L27). When you push, the build pack will detect all the enabled modules; include mod_access_compat from the configuration file and enable them.

Answer (score 0):

The error is due to changes beetween Apache 2.2 and 2.4. 'Order' is deprecated. Solution is described here: https://systembash.com/apache-2-4-upgrade-and-the-invalid-command-order-error/